# What are the steps needed to change our Office 365 domain name

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, domain, yammer

We have a newly added Office 365 tenant, and we chose a domain name as follow:

[image]

We added users to the tenant + 15 SharePoint sites + 10 Yammer communities.

But we need to change our Office 365 tenant's domain name, so is this possible? or we will need to create a new tenant with the new name and then migrate the users, SharePoint & yammer communities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to change the Office 365 domain name.

You have to create a new Office 365 tenant.

I will suggest you to create a support ticket with Microsoft. They will help you with this.